# PL/SQL Code Validation without execution

Tags: oracle, plsql

I would like to be able to validate that a piece of code is correct using only PL/SQL.

For example, I have the following code in a variable, I would like to validate it:

```
my_code:='BEGIN
           package1.get_wordlist_keywords_PG;
           package1.get_wordlist_keyword_cat_PG;
          END;
'
```

I would like to do something like:

result:=validate_code(my_code);

and result would be "valid" or "invalid"  (or with error message etc.)

I am sure this would be possible, as Oracle Apex allows users to enter PL/SQL and runs a validation on the code when it is saved.

I am on Oracle 12c.

Thanks!

P.S. - I do not need to validate a simple sql select, it needs to be a PL/SQL code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably put your code in a procedure instead of anonymous block.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p1 AS
BEGIN
  package1.get_wordlist_keywords_PG;
  package1.get_wordlist_keyword_cat_PG;
END;
/
show errors;
```

After the execution, the procedure may or may not be created successfully. Though the procedure is created successfully, the code inside the procedure
is not executed.

Comment: Thanks - turned it into this, which lets me validate what I need...

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE VALIDATE_PLSQL 
(
  PLSQL IN VARCHAR2 
, MY_RESULT OUT VARCHAR2 
) AS 
 my_code varchar2(31900);
 validate_code varchar2(32000);
 status varchar2(4000);
BEGIN
  my_code:=PLSQL;
  validate_code:='create or replace procedure testp1 AS '||my_code;

  BEGIN
   status:='PASSED';
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE validate_code;
  exception 
   when OTHERS then
   status:='FAILED';
  END;

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drop procedure testp1';

  MY_RESULT:=status;

END VALIDATE_PLSQL;
```

Pass in the block to be validated in "PLSQL" get the results in "MY_RESULT"

Clunky, but works!